# Помогите написать регулярку - только буквы и пробел, но чтобы строка не начиналась с пробела

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужно чтобы строка состояла только из букв и пробелов. Но чтобы не начиналась на пробел. Помогите, пожалуйста написать такую регулярку.
Вот у меня есть рабочий вариант с символами

```js
let value = ' Hello, world! 1345 '
value = value.replace(/[^A-zА-я\s]/g, '')
console.log(value)
```

Помогите пожалуйта дописать ее так, чтобы первым символом не мог быть пробел? Пробовал разные варианты, даже ужасного рабочего не получилось. Тиипа

```
/[^A-zА-я]{1}[^A-zА-я\s]$/g
/[^A-zА-я]{0,1}[^A-zА-я\s]$/g
/[\s+]{1}[^A-zА-я\s]$/g
```

И подскажите, пожалуйста, вроде был способ обознать все символы из любого языка? Чтобы не перечислять А-я

Comment: В вашем вопросе не совсем понятно, какой вам нужен результат. Т.е. есть пример строки. После этого делается replace. А вот какой результат вы хотите получить?

Comment: Строку, которая состоит только из букв и пробелов. Но первым идет НЕ пробел @newman

Comment: то есть вот к моей регулярке надо еще добавить, что первый символ тоже буква

Comment: `^[^\s][a-zA-Z\s]*$`?

Comment: @АлексейР Нет, первый пробел к сожалению остается на месте((

Comment: `.replace(/^\s+|[^A-ZА-я\s]/gi, '')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте

```js
text.replace(/^\s+|[^A-ZА-ЯЁ\s]/gi, '')
```

*Подробности*

- `^` - начало строки
- `\s+`  - один и более пробельных символов
- `|`  - или
- `[^A-ZА-ЯЁ\s]` - любой символ, отличный от русских кириллических и латинских букв и пробельных символов.

Answer (score 1):

Метасимвол `\p{L}` совпадает с любой буквой любого языка если регулярное выражение работает с Unicode (флаг `u`).

Это выражение требует чтобы первый символ был буквой, затем идёт любое число букв и пробельных символов:

```js
//           буква            Unicode
//           -----            -
const re = /^\p{L}[\s\p{L}]*$/u;
//                ----------
//                пробелы или буквы

console.log(re.test(' Hello'));
console.log(re.test('Hello, world!'));
console.log(re.test('Hello world '));
console.log(re.test(' Привет'));
console.log(re.test('Привет, мир!'));
console.log(re.test('Привет мир '));
```

Answer (score 1):

Суть выражения `/^(?:[^a-zA-Z]|\s)+|[^a-zA-Z\s]/g`:

- один или более недопустимых символов или пробелов с начала строки `^(?:[^a-zA-Z]|\s)+`
- или `|`
- не-буква и не-пробел в любом месте строки `[^a-zA-Z\s]`

заменяются на *пусто*

```js
[' Hello, world! 1345 ', '123456 aaa', '     BBB 145CCC__=+*/UUU'].forEach(value => {
  console.log(value.replace(/^(?:[^a-zA-Z]|\s)+|[^a-zA-Z\s]/g, ''))
})
```

Comment: trim не подходит, т.к. это в реалтайме валидация и с тримом не получится написать два слова через пробел((

Comment: так вам нужна проверка или чистка строки?

Comment: сделал без трим